# Pointiness for edge mask doesn't work at all

Tags: shaders, geometry

I'm trying to use the pointiness techniques to find the edges of my models, but I can't get it to work. I've tried googling, watching tutorials, but nothing has worked. I'm on 2.91, using Cycles with GPU rendering.

[image]

I've tried both the version with just pointiness in the color ramp, and also the dot product of Normal and Bevel shader. (I also tried connecting the color ramp directly to the shader). I just get black. (The white on the bottom left is an highlight from a light). I simply added some bevels to the cube to smooth it out.

[image]

I feel like I'm missing something dumb.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254798/110840

Answer (score 0):

Subdivide the cube. It requires more geometry to be displayed. "Dirty Vertex Colors" in Vertex Paint mode works the same way if you want to mask out edges and corners.

EDIT: No wait I just realised what's wrong. You should move the color stop sliders in the ColorRamp node more to the left. Tried setting it up like yours and it's all black here as well. Try 0.515 for the black stop's position.