# Create edge wear on bevelled cube

Tags: modeling, texturing, edges, displacement

Im trying to create an exterior shot of a car garage, and to make it photoreal, I would like to add imperfections/edge wear to the building, particularly the edges, as seen in the example below (see edges of garage building, building „frame“ around roll up doors).

[image]
[image]

How would you go about achieving this? I tried a boolean and some color changes using the bevel/geometry nodes but nothing comes close to this. How do I add dispacement on edges only without messing with my textures? Is it perhaps done by sculpting? In this case the building would need a lot of polygons, Like an insane amount?
How would you go about creating this effect on a bevelled cube, or go about modelling this garage in general to create this photorealistic look? I am grateful for any advice, as I am just starting out…

PS: Obviously the images are made by a famous CGI Expert that I admire a lot, so for the purpose of practising, im using his renders as inspiration (not trying to copy/steal anything).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your gut instinct is correct, that this isn't where you'd want to dedicate a bunch of geometry (system resources in the end).

This is a very simple shape with a bevel modifier

[image]

And shaded smooth with auto-smooth

[image]

And that should give the shader system the faces it needs to interpolate bump/height maps across that edge without a hard break.  Then you can stick to modeling simple shapes where you need them.  Just add one modifier.

[image]

Comment: Is this even an answer to your question?  I think your title is somewhat different from the content of your question.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry if my title is misleading, but the answer is getting there!

Comment: I wonder how this process can be taken a step further: obviously using a bump map for the normals means I cant use the normal map of any textures im using, which I find a bit limiting. 
In terms of color, in my reference the edge wear is in a darker color, I suppose this would have to happen manually?
Also, to make things a bit less even, can I add Vertices along the edges an make it a bit random? 
Finally, I see you extruded the wall instead of using a boolean like I have, I think that is also a good advice Thank you! :)

Comment: "using a bump map for the normals means I cant use the normal map of any textures im using", why that? You can use both actually...

Comment: @moonboots Ah! How? I always thought mixing normals was not really a viable option in Blender?

Comment: are you trying to mix height map with normal map? or 2 normal maps?

Comment: Im trying to have a seperate bump on the edges of my model, while maintaining the normal of the texture I am applying on the rest of the model. Im not sure what the best way of mixing would be… I guess the factor should somehow tell both normals how to split up: one for the edge and one for the rest of the model…?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254747/create-a-damaged-edge-with-shader-nodes/254798#254798 - a mask like this might be what you need @GSWarriors

Comment: Cool! Where would I plug the Ramp into? Would I use a Bump node to mix normals and use this mask in the factor? Or how do I achieve the mixing of two normals?

Comment: well if you just want to darken, you can use this mask as the factor of a Hue/Saturation node where you lower the value.  I'm not sure about mixing normals, maybe just mixrgb the normal output from both nodes.

Comment: Ill give it a try and let you know! Thanks for all the help so far!